# Django Class based and Function Based Views

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

everyone, I have one question. 
what is the difference between Class and Function-Based Views in Django and witch one is Good for Big and For low style Projects.  and why I should use Function or Class-based views.
thank you very much guys <3